# Quickbooks Online API Explorer only returns some Purchase

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

In QBO API explorer, for the Purchase API V3, when I tried to get all credit card transaction. The query I used was "select * from Purchase where PaymentType = 'CreditCard'". This only returned 4 transactions whose value for  is true, in other words, they are refunds. My most recent charges were not returned. The default value for this attribute is False. When I manually made those as true then they showed up.

Is there a way around this? I don't understand why by default only the refunds were returned by my query. I want all credit card transactions, not just refunds.

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#Purchase

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/purchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purchase entity query on PaymentType gives incorrect results. This is a known bug and will be resolved in our upcoming releases.
Bug number-QBO-35066
Refer-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq/qbo_v3_known_issues